# WordPress unexpected $wpdb error

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to develop my first WP full plugin / widget example. My problem occurs when I added a function to delete plugin table from database. But when I delete my plugin, an error shown `unexpected $wpdb`. I didn't understand exactly the problem, I used almost the same function to create table.

I am sorry because I am new in the WordPress development plugins.

Comment: Did you add "global $wpdb;" in your delete function ?

Comment: Please show your code so we can see what you might have done wrong. The more info you give the better an answer you will get :)

Comment: I think you are missing $wpdb global variable. Declare global $wpdb at start of the function

Comment: Yes absolutely I added $wpdb as global exacletly the same thing as the install function

Comment: @SimonPollard My code is very similar to this thread:
[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981357/unexpected-wpdb-unexpected-row-t-variable-in)

Comment: @Nozifel I added a global variable in my delete function.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `$wpdb` global variable by adding this code to the top of your delete function:

```
global $wpdb;
```

Comment: of course the global variable exists in the top of my function